# Javascript & Django: Event listener for form submit (Multiple forms using for loop) for AJAX

Tags: javascript, django, ajax, django-forms, django-templates

I tried posting before but I was not able to get a clear answer so I thought I would reframe it simply.

My template currently uses a for loop to print the posts of a "blog" and another for loop inside that to print comments belonging to the post.

**Before I continue**, just want to make it clear that my models and database is functioning. I even currently have a working comment section, it just keeps refreshing the page and so I would like to incorporate JS and AJAX instead.

Because I have multiple posts with their own comment sections, I tried creating individual id's for each form in the loop by saying . However, I am slightly confused as to how I am supposed to create an EventListener to make sure that no matter which of these forms are pressed, it takes the correct data and sends it to the backend.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you! Code upon request is available. However, I would like to stress that it is unnecessary to ask for my model code as it works just fine.

```html
{% for post in posts %}
        <div class="mt-3 px-5 pt-4 pb-2 bg-white shadow-sm" style="border-top-left-radius: 0.5rem; border-top-right-radius: 0.5rem;">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-1 pl-4">
                    <img class="rounded-circle post-image" src="{{ post.author.profile.image.url }}" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4 pt-1">
                    <a class="mr-2 post-author-name" href="#">{{ post.author.first_name }} {{ post.author.last_name }}</a>
                    <small class="text-muted post-time"><br>{{ post.date_posted|date:"F d, Y" }}</small>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-7 ml-3 pt-2">
                    <a href="{% url 'post-detail' society_id=membership.society.id pk=post.id %}" class="btn btn-light btn-sm">Click for more options</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <p class="post-content">{{ post.content }}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="mb-3 pr-5 pt-4 pb-2 bg-light shadow-sm border-light" style="border-bottom-left-radius: 0.5rem; border-bottom-right-radius: 0.5rem;">
            <div class="col-sm-12 pl-5 pb-5">
                <form class="form-inline" method="POST" style="display:flex" id="{{forloop.counter}}"> {% csrf_token %}
                    <input type="search" name="comment" placeholder="New comment" class="form-control mr-sm-2 p-4" style="flex-grow:1;">  
                    <button name="post_id" class="btn btn-info my-2 my-sm-0 " value="{{post.id}}" onclick='update_comments("{{forloop.counter}}")'> Post </button>
                </form>
            </div>
            {% for comment in post.comments.all %}
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-1 offset-1 pl-4">
                        <img class="rounded-circle comment-image" src="{{ comment.author.profile.image.url }}" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                        <a class="mr-2 comment-author-name" href="#">{{ comment.author.first_name }} {{ comment.author.last_name }}</a>
                        <small class="text-muted comment-time"><br>{{ comment.date_posted|date:"F d, Y" }}</small>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 offset-1">
                        <p class="comment-content">{{ comment.content }}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% empty %}
                <div class="px-5">
                    <p>No comments for this post.</p>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: If every blog post is a form, you can add an onsubmit listener to the form, and you can get the form by `event.target` in the event listener function, and you can get all the input, select and textarea elements within that form by `event.target.elements`. You can also add the onsubmit listener to the form in loop, like `<form onsubmit="formSubmitted(event)" >`

Comment: Hi Harshit! This sounds very close to what I need, but I would love a bit of a clarification. My posts are just normal posts with text and everything, and right below that is a comment section. The comment section has an input field to type a new one, a submit button, and then the list of comments of that specific post right below the input area. This pattern continues for all my posts, like a Facebook feed. I got lost at the point about adding the onsubmit listener. I am quite new to JS in general so I'd love a bit of guidance. Might accept it if you post as an answer!

Comment: I added some code above if it helps for a clearer answer!